# Tab panel - two cards - how to navigate to them

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this code:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.my_view', {
extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
xtype: 'myapp_myview',
config: {
    fullscreen:true,
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'top_bar'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'title_bar',
        },
        {
            title: 'TAB 1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'myapp_tab1_screen1',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'mayapp_tab1_screen2',
                },
            ]
         }
    ]
}
});
```

I want to have a button in screen1 that slides to screen2, this means that TAB 1 icon is still selected, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{
title:'firstTab',
id:'fTab',
}
```

{ title:'secondTab',
    id:'sTab',
after this u have to do some coding on handler fn of the button i.e.

```
handler:function(){
Ext.getCmp('sTab').show();
Ext.getCmp('fTab').hide();
}
}
```